# Browser image resize, better than highest PIL quality

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

**Preamble**

I'm displaying an image from a Django back-end into a `26 x 26px` sized (css) `<img>` tag.

I can do this two ways:

1. Resize on the back-end (Pillow) to `26x26` (cropping to keep the aspect ratio)
2. Send the full size image and let CSS do the sizing

---

**Issue**

Using the `LANCZOS` algorithm for resizing and saving the result as 100% quality Jpg, the displayed image looks so much worse than the one resized by the browser.

[image]

Why is that, and is there any way to fix it?

---

*EDIT*: Testing on a Retina display

*EDIT*: Bicubic looks very similar to Lanczos

[image]

Comment: Can you try bicubic interpolation and show the result?

Comment: I believe the LANCZOS algorithm is for enlarging images. I would suggest using `PIL.Image.BICUBIC`.

Comment: Edited. If anything, it looks a bit worse.

Comment: PIL documentation says that their lanczos algorithm had a bug causing bad quality. For some reason the LANCZOS implementation of Pillow 6.2.0 still produces very blurry enlargements, compared to Matplotlib's interpolation="lanczos", and to my own Numpy-based implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This article here [[1]](https://daraskolnick.com/image-dpi-web/) says that Retina displays (high-DPI displays) are going to try to display 2x more pixels in the same area. Area that is also measured in pixels, the pixels you actually declare in CSS.

So this is where my confusion came from. The solution was to generate the thumbnails twice the size being displayed.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, PIL/Pillow (hereafter simply “Pillow”) can behave very differently with small images than it does with large ones – not just in its resizing operations but generally – but so you might as well test out all of the methods Pillow offers, e.g.:

```py
# q.v. https://gist.github.com/fish2000/d85befaf289c664b6a9f44d1b56e57da#file-asscat-py-L129-L134

from PIL import Image

# q.v. PIL.Image constants of the same (yet uppercased) names:
interpolation_methods = frozenset({
                          "box",
                          "bilinear", "bicubic",
                          "hamming", "lanczos",
                          "nearest" })

def interpol(name):
    """ Return a PIL/Pillow image interpolation method constant by name """
    return getattr(Image, name.upper())

size    = (26, 26)
avatar  = Image.open(…) # load your source avatar image
methods = (interpol(method) for method in interpolation_methods)
scaled  = (avatar.resize(size, resample=method) for method in methods)

# you can save these out for more granular inspection:
previews = list(scaled)
for preview in previews:
    preview.show()
```

… keep in mind that `Image.NEAREST` can yield surprisingly decent results for small sizes – that, and the fact that Pillow is not in any way Adobe® Photoshop™, and as such can’t really be tasked with replicating results you may have gotten out of same.

But so, w/r/t whether or not to scale using CSS (or any other client-based method): it’s always better to send less bytes over the wire, if possible – but that doesn’t mean it can’t be done. I’m a perfectionist, personally, but if pressed for time or money I am not pedantic about it.

Comment: "always better to send less bytes over the wire", that's the only reason I'm bothering with back-end resizing. I hate the scan-line loading of a tiny avatar image.

Comment: I appreciate the bit at the end. Its always best to answer the implied question, even when providing a solution that should work for this specific scenario. It makes SO answers more applicable to folks who land here from search results. And real-world experience is always helpful for noobs.